# open my app from other apps if only logged in to the app

Tags: android

**I want to show my app in share list like below if only user is logged in my app.**

[image]

I know by following code i can add my app to share list.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

But is there a way to **show it if only user logged** in and to hide it **if user not logged in**.

Answer (score 0):

When the user is logged in register dynamically for the Intent.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                }
            };
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Also unregister when user logs out:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```